# how to convert the time from the database field into integer for hours, minutes, seconds separately through java?

Tags: java, sql-server

i am using the **DataType Time in my database** it stores the data in the form as **01:23:14.0000000.**
i am using dateTime controls of sWt as

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(cmpGrid, SWT.BORDER | SWT.TIME);
```

i can save the Value of DateTime easily as

```
String hours =String.valueOf(timeTo.getHours());
String minutes =String.valueOf(timeTo.getMinutes());
String seconds =String.valueOf(timeTo.getSeconds());
objhallModel.setClose_time(hours + ":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

For Editting purpose i need to set The time value in my design view For that i want to use

```
dateTime.setTime(hours, minutes, seconds);
```

it takes all hours, minutes, second in integer... can please anybody tell me how to set The time in DateTime of Database time value. thanks in advance

Comment: Not sure whether you want to set time into a DateTime from a Time, or into a Time from a DateTime.

Comment: on a side note imho it's not very convenient to store the date/time this way. you should store unix timestamp instead. if you want this column to be human-readable, then store 2 columns - one is in time format like you already have and another one in timestamp format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using [org.eclipse.swt.widgets.DateTime](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/swt/widgets/DateTime.html) in your user interface and [java.sql.Time](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) to store in your database.

I note that the javadoc of Time says:

> The date components should be set to
>   the "zero epoch" value of January 1,
>   1970 and should not be accessed.

Therefore, I think you should set it as follows:

```
DateTime dateTime; // you have this already

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(0); // set to zero epoch
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, dateTime.getHours());
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, dateTime.getMinutes());
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, dateTime.getSeconds());

Time time = new Time(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

The reverse operation (maybe this is what you want, I wasn't sure from your question) would be:

```
Time time; // you have this from your Database query
DateTime dateTime; // you have this already or will create a new one

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(time.getTime());
dateTime.setTime(calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR), calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE),calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND));
```

Comment: the reverse operation is the one i was looking.thank you, thank you, thank you........i appreciate for ur answer

Answer (score 0):

First get the date from the database - `Date date = resultset.getDate(int)` or `resultset.getDate(String)`, then

```
String hr = String.valorOf(date.getHours());
String min = String.valorOf(date.getMinutes());
String sec = String.valorOf(date.getSeconds());
```

Now you have the hour, minutes and the seconds.